# What is the best way to design MongoDB Schema for location based service

Tags: mongodb, database-design, geolocation, nosql, geojson

I am looking for a right database that supports location based search, found MongoDB supports GeoJSON Objects.

This is a Store Locator application, where user can look around and choose Store that's near to him for ordering products.

**Simple Vendor schema :**

```
const VendorSchema = new Schema({
    address: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please add address']
    },
    formattedAddress: {
        type: String
    },
    location: {
        type: {
          type: String,
          enum: ['Point']
        },
        // GeoJSON Points
        coordinates: {
          type: [Number],
          index: '2dsphere'
        },
        formattedAddress: String,
        street: String,
        city: String,
        state: String,
        zipcode: String,
        country: String
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});
```

Database will have many FMCG Products that multiple Vendors could be selling.

**Product Schema :**

```
const ProductSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    desc: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    price: Number,
    createdAt: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now
    }
});
```

> A Vendor can sell multiple Products and a Product could be sold by many Vendors, there's `N-to-N` relationship between Vendors & Products.

So was thinking of creating a new Schema, **VendorProduct Schema :**

```
const VendorProductSchema = new Schema({
    price: Number,
    discountVal: Number,
    vendor : { 
        type: ObjectId, 
        ref: 'Vendor' 
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now
    }
});
```

**This is where its getting tricky / challenging :**

> User's can either look-up for **Vendor/Stores** around them or can also directly search for a **Product**.

If asked to find Vendors, its straight look up in the Vendors collection with-in certain Radius.

```
Vendor.find({"location.coordinates": {$geoWithin: {$centerSphere: [[User long, User lat], 1/6378.15]}}})
```

But when user searches for a Product :

System should send back searched Product(s) details along with near by Vendors who are selling them - from closest to farthest, in certain radius.

For this reason i was thinking of storing Vendor's GeoJSON location details for a Product in VendorProduct schema.

**VendorProduct Schema with GeoJSON details :**

```
const VendorProductSchema = new Schema({
    price: Number,
    discountVal: Number,
    vendor : { 
        type: ObjectId, 
        ref: 'Vendor' 
    },
    location: {
        type: {
          type: String,
          enum: ['Point']
        },
        // GeoJSON Points
        coordinates: {
          type: [Number],
          index: '2dsphere'
        }
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now
    }
});
```

Let's say user searches with keyword ONIONS. It will be found in Products collection, will use ProductID and in-turn filter them in VendorProducts collection based on Geo co-ordinates. In that way i can pull Product info like description, images from Products collection & Vendor, Prices info from VendorProducts collection.

This is only keeping in mind, a single Product can be sold by multiple Vendors. When user searches with a Product name - there could be N number of sellers of this product at different prices. But to find only closest vendors, was thinking of storing Vendor location details against Product in VendorProductSchema.

**FEW QUESTIONS :**

1. Is it right to use MongoDB for such use-case ?
2. Is this the right design and approach ?
3. What is the time complexity of such Geo location searches in MongoDB ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my understanding, you should only save the location coordinates in Vendor Schema only, because they are related to vendors. Your old VendorProduct Schema is fine

**Case1: User is looking for nearby vendors**

You need to run a query to find the vendors on the basis of the user's location and provide the vendors listing to the user

For that, you need to run

```
Vendor.find({"location.coordinates": {$geoWithin: {$centerSphere: [[User long, User lat], 1/6378.15]}}})
```

**Case2: User is looking for products he/she can find nearby**

In that case, also search for nearby vendors first by the above query (**Remember there will be limited no of vendors nearby, if not you need to reduce the search radius**).

Once you get all the nearby vendors, save their ids in an array, let's call it

```
vendorArray = [vendor_id1, vendor_id2.....]
```

Then search for products in VendorProduct schema

```
VendorProduct.find({
  vendor : {
    $in: vendorArray
  }
})
```

The above solution was just for an alternative to store location information in VendorProductSchema

Now you need to get the product details after getting product ids from vendorProduct collection, I would suggest you should add product name or any other field in vendorProduct by which you want to search or filter

**Downside of current approach**
There are few downsides storing location coordinates in VendorProduct

- You are saving redundant data in multiple collections and you will be
  maintaining them while add/edit/delete VendorProduct records
- VendorProduct collection will contain the multifold no of records in
  comparison to Vendor collection, The geojson queries require more
  computational power than a basic search.
- When your database scales, It is more efficient to run geojson query
  on a few thousand of record in Vendor instead of 100 of thousands
  records in VendorProduct

Comment: My perspective : Lets say user searches with keyword ONIONS. It will be found in Products collection, will use ProductID and in-turn filter them in VendorProducts collection based on Geo co-ordinates. In that way i can pull Product info like description, images from Products collection & prices of near by vendors from VendorProducts collection. That is my only reason to be inclined towards storing Geo co-ordinates against VendorProduct collection.

Comment: Both the cases have merits and demerits,  depends on the size of the collection if there are fewer records then your solution works fine, will give you results in 2 query only, but if the VendorProduct will be a large collection geojson query will be slow

In my solution you may need to run 3 queries if you first search the products by name, then vendor by geojson, and then search the the VendorProducts including both vendor_id and product_ids you have, IT will be efficient even there are many records in VendorProducts, you can do indexing on vendor_id or product_id

Answer (score 0):

I know only basic MongoDB but I noticed that you're storing location data in the VendorProduct collection. In this case if say the vendor edit their coordinates then multiple documents would need to be updated.

Instead you can keep location in the Vendor collection itself. While querying you can do a nested query to fetch products of given name where vendors have coordinate values less then x, y. Syntax-

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/

Comment: Vendor updating location co-ordinates is rare one time activity & updating co-ordinates of related VendorProducts is not much of an ask. But User querying for Products through text search is a very frequent operation.

Answer (score 0):

1. Is it right to use MongoDB for such use-case ?

Yes, I don't see why not. MongoDB supports geoJSON and allows for many ways to query easily query this information.

2. Is this the right design and approach ?

If I'm understanding your situation:

> User's can either look-up for Vendor/Stores around them or can also directly search for a product. As its a location based service - system should send Products that are around user, so was thinking of storing Vendor's GeoJSON location details in VendorProduct schema so that system can query only Products that are around user with Vendor details.

Given a specific point (user location), find vendors within a given radius that have products available.

Since products can have multiple vendors, and the vendors are where the locations are, there is no reason to duplicate the location of the vendor. If you did store the vendor location info in two places, like vendors and products, then you no longer have a single point of truth for your application. It becomes a  big mess to try and keep those documents in sync. If you want to seperate anything, I would separate the location of the vendors to a stand-alone indexed collection (vendorGEO in the below example), and adjust the current vendor documents to point to this new collection instead. This way, you can query which vendors are nearby the user, then grab the vendors, and then pull only the vendors you need, and search through their products.

Here's a mongo shell example to find all locations, unsorted, based on the radius (circle) of a point (user location)

```
db.vendorGEO.createIndex({location: "2dsphere"})

db.vendorGEO.find({location: {$geoWithin: {$centerSphere: [[User long, User lat], 1/6378.15]}}})
```

*mile: 1/3963.2 radians 
km: 1/6378.15 radians*

Official docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/centerSphere/index.html

You could instead use a Polygon. A polygon would be more useful if you had a pre-defined area, like within city limits:

A Polygon, which needs four points, and the original starting point. Note the way the coordinates are set up using nested arrays:

```
db.collection.find({location: {$geoWithin: {$geometry: {type: "Polygon", coordinates: [[[point 1], [point 2], [point 3], [point 4], [point 1 again]]]}}}})
```

To store polygon information easily, store them in a separate collection

```
db.areas.insertOne({name: "Example Location", area: {type: "Polygon", coordinates: [[[longA, latA], [longB, latB], [longC, latC], [longD, latD], [longA, latA]]]}})
```

To find if a point is inside the polygon, search for a point within the polygon, referencing the area field defined

```
db.areas.find({area: {$geoIntersects: {$geometry: {type: "Point", coordinates: [longA, latA]}}}})
```

3. What is the time complexity of such Geo location searches in MongoDB
   ?

When using $geoIntersects or $geoWithin, you do not need an index, but adding it is advisable to speed up your queries.

For any concern of time complexity, you can see what is going on under the hood by using the `.explain()` command to dive deeper into query planning/optimization.

Comment: But how to find Products nearby, when user searches with text ? That's where i need help & am thinking of tagging geo co-ordinates against Products too.

Comment: See my previous mention of duplicating data. You should provide a link to the vendor who has the product, rather than the product which has the address.

Case A: User searches for product: Query products in list (many ways to acheive this, text index for instance), get your list of products and their associated vendor(s), further filter by vendor location if necessary and return result. 

Case B: User wants products nearby them. Query vendors nearby to user, and list all their products.